# Infinite loop with string iterator in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, infinite-loop

While i'm willing to parse instructions contained in strings, I am basically trying to clean a string from it's spaces and tabs character, in order to seek instructions in it.
Unfortunately, my loop is going into an infinite loop, and I can't find why as i'm refreshing the iterator on each erasing of a char...

Any Help please?

```
void  myClass::parseInstructions(std::string& line)
{
    std::string::iterator        it;

    for (it = line.begin(); it != line.end(); ++it)
        if (((*it) == ' ') || ((*it) == '\t'))
            it = line.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: I think the association of CPU rights will sue you for this code (hint: this is O(n^2) in the length of the string... isn't there a better way?)

Comment: @6502: Better way already mentioned in my answer...

Comment: What do you mean about "CPU rights"?

Comment: @6502: Of course there is: `line.erase(std::remove_if(line.begin(),line.end(),[](char c){ return c == ' ' || c == '\t'; }),line.end());` (replacing the lambda with a function if you don't have access to them)

Comment: @PigBen: couldn't you just use `isspace` for the predicate (assuming that there are no linefeed characters in the string)?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Yes, but I didn't assume that there were no linefeed characters in the string.

Comment: @PigBen: The variable is named `line`... I think it's a reasonable assumption that it contains a single line with no embedded linebreaks.  Of course we'll need @oleiade to tell us for sure.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Either way, he's got the solution for both cases now.

Comment: @oleiade: It was just a joke. `std::string::erase` and `std::vector::erase` have O(n) complexity. If you need to call them in a loop on a container there's probably a better way...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The flow of your code:

```
it = line.begin(); 
while (it != line.end()) {
    if (((*it) == ' ') || ((*it) == '\t'))
        it = line.erase(it);
    ++it;
}
```

Correct code:

```
it = line.begin(); 
while (it != line.end()) {
    if (((*it) == ' ') || ((*it) == '\t'))
        it = line.erase(it);
    else // <---- THIS IS IMPORTANT
        ++it;
}
```

Right now you'll miss two whitespace characters in a row, and when the final character is whitespace you'll move right past the end.

Or you could just use `std::remove_copy_if`, which should have much lower complexity.

Comment: Seems to make it! thank you very much!
But, why is string.erase() returning an iterator if it's not in order to automatically get an updated one without having to do this iterator move by hand?

Comment: It could return the equivalent of line.end() if you delete the last character, so you'll end up calling `++` on that.

Comment: @oleiade: It returns an iterator for the character you need to process next... so you need to process it, and not just call `++it`.

Comment: @oleiade: If you look at what `erase()` returns, it returns the **next** element already.  It is wrong to call both `erase()` and `++it`, each of which will move the iterator forward one spot.  Your code would work if `erase()` returned an iterator such that `++it` points to the next element, but sadly that is not the case, `erase()` already points to the next element.

Comment: Ok! I got now!,I've just been spotting std::remove_copy_if and it seems to be a better/simplier/more efficient solution to my problem.

Comment: @sbi: `erase` returns a valid iterator (which may be `.end()`).  He's not using the iterator he had before erasure.

Answer (score 2):

C++0x solution:

```
void  myClass::parseInstructions(std::string& s)
{
      std::string::iterator end = std::remove_if(s.begin(),s.end(),[](char c){ return c==' ' || c == '\t'; });
      s.erase(end, s.end());
}
```

Demo in which removing only `a` : http://www.ideone.com/hgnCN

---

C++03 Solution

```
bool predicate(char c) { return c==' ' || c == '\t'; }
void  myClass::parseInstructions(std::string& s)
{
      std::string::iterator end = std::remove_if(s.begin(),s.end(),predicate);
      s.erase(end, s.end());
}
```

Demo in which removing `r` now : http://www.ideone.com/W5unx

Comment: The C++03 version is relying on another new C++0x feature - local struct used for a template argument.

Comment: Your functor has no state, so just use an ordinary function, like maybe `isspace` from `ctype.h`.  Also, the C++0x solution probably ought to use `auto end = `...